# can someone change the data sent to the server if I have the data in a div

Tags: javascript, mongodb, security, express, heroku

I got questions about security. lets say I have data in a div like so

```
<div id="Q9vX" class="mainContent" data-compname="comp1" data-user="57f70c8e78ae49d41c78876a" data-shortid="Hy85nKVR">
```

and I do a post request that sends the `compname` and user id .Couldn't someone change the `data-user` attribute value before it was sent? Since I'm doing DB operations based on the ID in the div can someone change the id and have the operation occur for the id the villain entered and not the one I initially intended.  . I use mongodb, heroku, express. I'm afraid of sessions because they expire and I'm not too comfortable with them. What is the standard procedure for something like this?

For example this div is for a review placed by a user that has the id `57f70c8e78ae49d41c78876a`. So if everything went normal and the user presses submit the review will be assigned to that users's Id. but lets say someone decides to go into firebug  and changes the id would the review be registered to this new ID?

Comment: Yes, if you grab the data from the DOM when submitting. The DOM can be edited using developer tools built into almost every major browser. If you want to store important information, do it in JavaScript, a session cookie, or some other non-editable memory.

Answer (score 1):

The value could be changed a user through the developer tools or through a [cross site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack where malicious code is injected onto the page. This could be done a number of ways such as adding the code to a file on your server, adding the code to your database if it uses a CMS, or through another means such as a browser extension.

If you have no server side access controls, someone could write a script that compromises the availability or integrity of your data. The availability could be compromised through a denial of service attack where thousands of fake requests are sent to the server trying to exceed the number of concurrent database connections preventing a legitimate user from connecting. The data integrity could be compromised by sending lots of fake requests to the database which could be difficult and time consuming to identify and remove. Also if the review is like a comment box where users can enter data that's displayed on the site, it could be used to inject malicious cross site scripting code.

If you are concerned about security I recommend that you implement access control such as sessions, sanitize the data coming in and going out of your database, and use a secure HTTP connection on your web server.

The Express JS website have an article about [security best practices](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html).